# How to enable multiple Authorization roles to access control

Tags: asp.net-core

How do I allow more than one user role for Authorization like the one below:

```
[Authorize(Roles="members", "admin")]
```

I have tried other answers, but it is not working in the ASP.Net Core decorator. I tried
`[Authorize(Roles="members,admin")]` and `[Authorize(Roles="members" + "," + "admin")]`. When I set any of these, the authorization is not working at all.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Your second approach (`[Authorize(Roles="members,admin")]`) is correct.